# How to loop through 2 arrays and find matching/missing values

Tags: php

I currently have 2 arrays;

`$last_12_months` - contains an array of the last 12 months from the current month

`$app12_array_temp` - contains a query result with a count of appointments made in that month, and a month.

I need to be able to loop through each month, and assign an appointment count to that month.

As i am nesting the loop, i am getting this as a result:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,"4",0,0,0,0,0,0,"2",0,0,0,0,0,0,"15",0,0,0,0,0,0,"9",0,0,0,0,0,0,"8",0,0,0,0,0,0,"2",0,0,0,0,0,0,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

What I need is:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,4,2,15,9,8,2,1]
```

my current script is:

```
//Loop through months, and check if appointments happened in that month 
  foreach($last_12_months as $m => $month){
    foreach($app_12_array_temp AS $app){
      if(date("m", strtotime($app['time'])) == date("m", strtotime($month))){
        $app_12_array[] = $app['count'];
        break;
      }else{
        $app_12_array[] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

So if there is an appointment in that month, it should add the appointment count to an array, else add 0.
Currently, it is adding 0 every time the loop isnt that corresponding month

I have tried using Breaks when condition met but will return 0 up until it finds that data.

I have also `tried In_Array()`, but just returns `[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

This is what the script should be thinking, but I can't think of how to get it to do this:

```
Jan -> Any data for this month? -> No, so add 0 for this month to array
Feb -> Any data for this month? -> No, so add 0 for this month to array
Mar -> Any data for this month? -> Yes, so add $app['count'] to array
Apr -> Any data for this month? -> Yes, so add $app['count'] to array
May -> Any data for this month? -> Yes, so add $app['count'] to array
```

EDIT

```
$app_12_array_temp = [
    ['time' => '2019-07-27 13:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
    ['time' => '2019-08-26 13:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2019-09-06 13:00:00', 'count' => '8'],
    ['time' => '2019-10-22 12:00:00', 'count' => '9'],
    ['time' => '2019-11-21 12:00:00', 'count' => '15'],
    ['time' => '2019-12-27 11:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2020-01-22 15:00:00', 'count' => '4'],
    ['time' => '2020-02-12 09:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
];

$last_12_months = ['Feb', 'Jan', 'Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'May', 'Apr', 'Mar'];
```

Comment: Hello, can you add the content of the `$last_12_months` and `$app_12_arr_temp`  arrays to the question, please ?

Comment: Done :) Added it as an edit

Comment: _“contains a query result with a count of appointments made in that month, and a month”_ - not really, it contains a specific date, instead of an actual month. Do you have ensured there will be only one per month, or could it be more?

Comment: The result groups by month so will only ever be 1 record for each month, with a count of how many in that month. As you can tell, in the loop, I extracted the month from the timestamp. No result is given back if no appointments for the grouped month. so hence I need to loop through each month and check if there is a matching month in the appointment array.

Comment: I would get rid of the nested loops here to begin with. Convert `$last_12_months` to an array that uses the month name as key, and is initialized with 0 for each entry. Then you only need to loop over your $last_12_months _once_, to fill the counts you find in there into the other array under the appropriate key.

Comment: … or get rid of the second array with the month names altogether. You _have_ all the info you need in your first array already, all you’d need to do is format those dates as just the month name, instead of sticking one arbitrary date somewhere _in_ the month in there.

Comment: @MaxResnikoff why do you want this pattern `[0,0,0,0,1,4,2,15,9,8,2,1]` ? I can't see any logic in the values specified, either if I go from Mars 2019 - February 2020 or if I reverse it and go backwards it doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, using the month as the key for the new array

```
$app_12_array_temp = [
    ['time' => '2019-07-27 13:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
    ['time' => '2019-08-26 13:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2019-09-06 13:00:00', 'count' => '8'],
    ['time' => '2019-10-22 12:00:00', 'count' => '9'],
    ['time' => '2019-11-21 12:00:00', 'count' => '15'],
    ['time' => '2019-12-27 11:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2020-01-22 15:00:00', 'count' => '4'],
    ['time' => '2020-02-12 09:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
];

$last_12_months = ['Feb', 'Jan', 'Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'May', 'Apr', 'Mar'];


$app_12_array = array_fill_keys( $last_12_months, 0 );
foreach ( $last_12_months as $m => $month )
{
    foreach ( $app_12_array_temp AS $app )
    {
        if ( date( "m", strtotime( $app['time'] ) ) == date( "m", strtotime( $month ) ) )
        {
            $app_12_array[ $month ] = ($app_12_array[ $month ] ?? 0 ) + $app['count'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump( $app_12_array );
```

Comment: This is returning something closer to what i am looking for, but not in same order as the last 12 months array, and months that dont have data should show as 0 in the array for that corresponding month. The result of your suggestion:
{"Feb":1,"Jan":4,"Dec":2,"Nov":15,"Oct":9,"Sep":8,"Aug":2,"Jul":1}

Comment: (see edit) you can initialize the "template" array with 0

Comment: Had issues with your solution only to find that it didnt like converting $month to a date()... so just left it as $month rather than DATE('m', strtotime($month))

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can solve your problem, using a `do-while loop`. This can easily be used for a shorter/longer range of period then 12 months by modifying the `$dateFirst` variable.

**Code:**

```
$data = [
    ['time' => '2019-07-27 13:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
    ['time' => '2019-08-26 13:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2019-09-06 13:00:00', 'count' => '8'],
    ['time' => '2019-10-22 12:00:00', 'count' => '9'],
    ['time' => '2019-11-21 12:00:00', 'count' => '15'],
    ['time' => '2019-12-27 11:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2020-01-22 15:00:00', 'count' => '4'],
    ['time' => '2020-02-12 09:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['time']) - strtotime($b['time']);
});

if (!is_array($data) || count($data) === 0) {
    die('no data');
}

$dateFirst = (date('Y', time()) - 1) . date('-m', time());

// begin 11 months ago instead of 12 [start]
if (date('n', strtotime($dateFirst)) == 12) {
    $dateFirst = (date('Y', strtotime($dateFirst)) + 1) . '-01';
} else {
    $newMonth = (date('n', strtotime($dateFirst)) + 1);
    $dateFirst = date('Y', strtotime($dateFirst)) . '-' . ($newMonth <= 9 ? '0' . $newMonth : $newMonth);
}
// begin 11 months ago instead of 12 [end]

$dateCurrent = $dateFirst;
$tsDateNow = strtotime(date('Y-m', time()));

$result = [];

do {
    if (!isset($result[$dateCurrent])) {
        $result[$dateCurrent] = 0;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $dateCheck = date('Y-m', strtotime($data[$i]['time']));

        if ($dateCheck === $dateCurrent) {
            $result[$dateCurrent] += $data[$i]['count'];
        }
    }

    if (date('n', strtotime($dateCurrent)) == 12) {
        $dateCurrent = (date('Y', strtotime($dateCurrent)) + 1) . '-01';
    } else {
        $newMonth = (date('n', strtotime($dateCurrent)) + 1);
        $dateCurrent = date('Y', strtotime($dateCurrent)) . '-' . ($newMonth <= 9 ? '0' . $newMonth : $newMonth);
    }

} while (strtotime($dateCurrent) <= $tsDateNow);
// exclude this month:
// } while (strtotime($dateCurrent) < $tsDateNow);

print_r($result);
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [2019-03] => 0
    [2019-04] => 0
    [2019-05] => 0
    [2019-06] => 0
    [2019-07] => 1
    [2019-08] => 2
    [2019-09] => 8
    [2019-10] => 9
    [2019-11] => 15
    [2019-12] => 2
    [2020-01] => 4
    [2020-02] => 1
)
```

This code will also sum all `count` if you have multiple elements with different dates within the same month.

So if you have the following array:

```
$data = [
    ['time' => '2019-07-27 13:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
    ['time' => '2019-08-26 13:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2019-09-06 13:00:00', 'count' => '8'],
    ['time' => '2019-10-22 12:00:00', 'count' => '9'],
    ['time' => '2019-07-04 09:00:00', 'count' => '1000'],
    ['time' => '2019-11-21 12:00:00', 'count' => '15'],
    ['time' => '2019-12-27 11:00:00', 'count' => '2'],
    ['time' => '2020-01-22 15:00:00', 'count' => '4'],
    ['time' => '2020-02-12 09:00:00', 'count' => '1'],
];
```

This will be the output:

```
Array
(
    [2019-03] => 0
    [2019-04] => 0
    [2019-05] => 0
    [2019-06] => 0
    [2019-07] => 1001
    [2019-08] => 2
    [2019-09] => 8
    [2019-10] => 9
    [2019-11] => 15
    [2019-12] => 2
    [2020-01] => 4
    [2020-02] => 1
)
```